# Datetime with offset?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, hour

`Datetime.Today` changes at exactly **midnight** to the **next day**.

Is there any way of making the **day change** at **3am** instead of 12?

Using **c#**

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3)

Comment: "Is there a way of making the day change just at 3am for example, instead of 12?" No, that doesn't make any sense. The day changes at 00:00. Are you talking about _different time zones?_

Comment: No I actually mean exactly that. I need the application to think that a new day starts at a different time then 00:00, for example 3am.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Read about the `DateTimeOffset` class. I think this should more correctly solve your problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset